# Separate file for every controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, controller, single-page-application

Is it a good idea to place every controller in a separate file in ASP.NET MVC (SPA with Web API) project and use bundling to combine one single file later?

Comment: Yes. Make sure the module setters are loaded first and use the array syntax or $inject to declare your dependencies so they survive minification.

Comment: Have to agree with @AnthonyChu, yes.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.angularjs.org/2014/02/an-angularjs-style-guide-and-best.html

You should separate the files based on the app structure guide here. Use grunt or gulp as task managers to concat everything into one file.